# Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=L$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to o^+}{f(\frac{1}{x})}=L.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=L$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to o^+}{f(\frac{1}{x})}=L.$

My work so far:
$(\implies)$

Given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $x>M$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. I need to show: Given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ so that is $0<x-0<\delta$, then $|F(\frac{1}{x} - L | < \epsilon$. Since it is assumed that $x>M$ we know that $\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{M}$. So I chose $\delta = \frac{1}{M}$. This is where I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not too bad! 
Let $\delta=\frac{1}{M}$. Then $0<x<\delta$ means $x<\frac{1}{M}$ or $\frac{1}{x}>M$. But we know that $|f(y)-L|<\varepsilon$ for all $y$ with $y>M$, hence also for those values of $\frac{1}{x}$ which satisfy that $\frac{1}{x}>M$. Hence, $|f(1/x)-L|<\varepsilon$ for all $0<x<\delta$ (since for those $x$ we have $1/x>M$)