# How do you prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Given $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(\frac{1}{x})$$
I need to prove it with a simple proof using $\epsilon-\delta$.
So, here is what I ve got so far:

Given $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) = L$ if, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $|x-0|<\delta \implies$  $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

We have that $\lim_{y\to -\infty} g(y) = M$ if, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $N$ such that for all $y<N \implies$ $|g(y)-M|<\varepsilon$.

Taking functions such that $g(y)=f(1/y)$.

Consider the limit  $$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x) = L \exists$$
 , then for any $\varepsilon>0$ find a $\delta>0$, so that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ for $|x|<\delta$. Let $N=\frac{1}{\delta}$.

So, if $y<N$ then $\frac{1}{y}\in (0,\delta)$ so $$|g(y)-L| = |f(\frac{1}{y})-L| < \varepsilon$$

So, $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) = L$ then $\lim_{y\to -\infty} f(1/y) = L$, too.

$\lim_{y\to -\infty} g(y) = L$, then, given $\varepsilon>0$ and $N \in \mathbb{R}$, we can take $\delta>0 = \frac{1}{N}$ if $N<0$ and $\delta = 1$ if $N\leq 0$.

Such that  $N'=\max(N,1)$.

So, we can conclude $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(\frac{1}{x})$$
Suggestions will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You start with the definition of $\lim_{x\to 0}$ instead of $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$

Comment: I know. I m really a begginer. Just doing my best. I m struggling a little bit here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=L$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to o^+}{f(\frac{1}{x})}=L.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724337/let-f0-infty-to-mathbbr-prove-that-lim-x-to-inftyfx-l-if-and)

Comment: Oh! thank you. It's going to be useful . I have a question. What is the difference between x→0+ and x→0− ?. I realize how much is different when I compare limits to - or + infinity, but I m struggling with limits from sides inside the proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea is correct, but it could be much cleaner. Also, in your $\delta$ claims, you are using absolute values and aren't avoiding the $x=0$ case (you should have $-\delta<x<0$, not $|x|<\delta$). All you have to do is:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $-\delta<x<0$ $\iff$ there exists $M:=1/\delta$ such that $|f(1/x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $x<-M$.

Comment: Oh!. Got it. So from left side is $ x\rightarrow 0-$ because you consider $-\delta <x<0$ and for the positive case  ,Right side  is $ x\rightarrow 0+$ therefore you consider $\delta <x<0$ . Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple.

Suppose $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=L$, finite. You want to prove that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(1/x)=L$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then, by assumption, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $-\delta<x<0$, we have $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Set $K=1/\delta$. Then, if $x<-K$, we have $-\delta<1/x<0$, hence $|f(1/x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Now do similarly for $L=\pm\infty$.

Finally, adapt the proof to show the converse.